# Why I am getting invalid token error when I am giving the right token

Tags: python-3.x, bearer-token

I am trying to get data from Zendesk using Python. They have the following instruction in their [API documentation](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/sales-crm/search/custom-fields-mapping/#custom-fields). Though I am giving the right API token, I am getting an invalid authorization error.

**Zendesk doc:**

```
GET /v3/deals/custom_fields
Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN
```

**My attempt:**

```
import requests            
import json

domain = 'https://mydomain.zendesk.com/v3/deals/custom_fields.json'
api_token= 'apikey'

payload = ""
headers = {
    'Accept': "application/json",
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'Authorization': "Bearer "+api_token
    }
response1=requests.request("GET", domain, data=payload, headers=headers)
response1.json()
```

**Error:**

> {'error': 'invalid_token',
> 'error_description': 'The access token provided is expired, revoked, malformed or invalid for other reasons.'}

Comment: Bearer Token is valid for 600 seconds (10mins) you have to refresh it, before you can send new request if the time is passed
And do json.loads(response1)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I connect with a token to Zendesk API :

```
Authorization: Basic {email_address}/token:{api_token}
```

Don't use `Bearer` but `Basic` instead.

We need to base64 encode {email_address}/token:{api_token}

Example :

If you have :

```
jdoe@example.com/token:6wiIBWbGkBMo1mRDMuVwkw1EPsNkeUj95PIz2akv
```

Then :

```
Authorization: Basic amRvZUBleGFtcGxlLmNvbS90b2tlbjo2d2lJQldiR2tCTW8xbVJETXVWd2t3MUVQc05rZVVqOTVQSXoyYWt2
```

> Basic authentication is used for API tokens. As described in Basic
> authentication above, the credentials must be sent with the request in
> an Authorization header.

source : https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/introduction/security-and-auth/#api-token